# Laravel Categories, Subcategories and model binding

Tags: laravel, eloquent, categories, laravel-8, model-binding

I have two tables: products and categories. Every product have specific category.

The products table has category_id.
The categories table has name and parent_id.

This is my example product: iPhone 12.
In the admin section I have category Apple and subcategory iPhone and then I put the product (iPhone 12) inside the subcategory iPhone.

In the frontend section I can successfully display the category tree unordered list and when I click on the subcategory iPhone, the product iPhone 12 displays fine but when I click on the category Apple, the product doesn't show. How can I display the data from the parent, so when I click on Apple category or iPhone subcategory to display the product in both cases?

Here's my code:

Model category

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Product');
}

public function children() {
  return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Category', 'parent_id');
}
```

Category model

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Product');
}
```

ProductController

```
public function productCategory(Category $category) {
  $categories = Category::with('children')->whereNull('parent_id')->where('status',1)->get();
  $products = $category->products;

  return view('products', compact('products', 'categories'));

}
```

Route

```
Route::get('/category/{category:slug}', 'App\Http\Controllers\ProductController@productCategory')->name('product.category');
```

Products view:

```
  <div class="content products">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="categories">
            <ul>
              @foreach($categories as $category)
                <li>
                  <a href="{{ route('product.category', $category->slug) }}">{{ $category->name }}</a>
                  @if($category->children)
                  <ul>
                    @foreach($category->children as $child)
                      <li>
                        <a href="{{ route('product.category', $child->slug) }}">{{ $child->name }}</a>
                      </li>
                    @endforeach
                  </ul>
                  @endif
                </li>
              @endforeach
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
          <div class="row">
            @foreach($products as $product)
              <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="image">
                  <a href="{{ route('product', $product->slug) }}"><img class="img-fluid" src="{{ Storage::url($product->image) }}" /></a>
                </div>
                <div class="title">
                  <h3>{{ $product->title }}</h3>
                </div>
              </div>
            @endforeach
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please show your category model.

Comment: Are you able to fetch $slug name in productCategory Function?

Comment: @Shahrukh I've updated my post.

Comment: @YasinPatel Yes, with dd($category); I'm getting all data including the slug.

Comment: @user2519032, currently you are getting all products? bcs you are not using $category anywhere

Comment: @YasinPatel I'm getting all products with my other method called products and they are fine.
The issue is related with this category model binding when there are categories and subcategories.

Comment: Guys, please check the live link that I just added in my main post and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use `hasManyThrough` function provided by laravel

In the category model add these functions

```
//retrunt only the subcategories of the category 
public function subcategories()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Category::class,'parent_id');
}
//return the products directly by the parent category
public function categotyProducts()
{
   return $this->hasManyThrough(
        Product::class,
        category::class,
        'parent_id', 
        'category_id', 
    );
}
```

for more information see the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)

Hope that works for you!

Answer (score 0):

In your `Product` model define category relationship as below.

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Category','category_id');
}
```

In your controller function define slug variable and use below query to get Products

```
$slug = ($category->slug)??'';
```

Query for products:

```
$products = Product::where(function($query) use ($slug){
                            $query->whereHas('category',function($q) use ($slug){
                              $q->where('name', 'like', '%' . $slug . '%');
                            })
                            ->orWhereHas('category.children',function($q) use ($slug){
                              $q->where('name', 'like', '%' . $slug . '%');
                            });
                          })->get();
```

Comment: I've just tried now and I'm getting syntax error. You can check the link.

Comment: which one, bcs i just type here

Comment: Add ; after orwhereHas

Comment: I'm still getting the same error. You can see in the live link from my main post.

Comment: copy the query now

Comment: just got edited. The products page is working again as it should but now when you click on any category from left, you'll see "Undefined variable: q"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232640/discussion-between-yasin-patel-and-user2519032).

Comment: have you checked now

Comment: Still getting eror?

Comment: I've copied the query again. The error is gone but it still the same situation as before. Check my live link again. If you click on iPhone, you'll see the product but if you click on Apple, the product is not displayed.

Comment: have you removed this line:   $products = $category->products;

Comment: I've sent you the full code of the controller in the Stackoverflow's chat. Please check.